# how to get email id using oauth

Tags: java, security, oauth, yahoo, scribe

I'm trying to get user profile information by using following code. I'm using scribe to get the information. I'm able to get familyName and givenName etc. but it is not returning me the email id.

I'm using the following code:

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(
    Verb.GET,
    "https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid? format=xml"
); 
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
request.addHeader("realm", "yahooapis.com"); 
Response response = request.send();
```

And this is the response I got:

```
{
    "profile": {
        "guid":"CGGT5LNT7NXGFK64QW7FQN5UQM",
        "ageCategory":"A",
        "familyName":"gto",
        "givenName":"CTSDemo",
        "image": {
            "height":192,
            "imageUrl":"https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/social/profile/profile_b192.png",
            "size":"192x192",
            "width":192
        },
        "intl":"us",
        "jurisdiction":"us",
        "lang":"en-US",
        "location":"Bangalore",
        "memberSince":"2014-08-03T08:23:27Z",
        "nickname":"CTSDemo",
        "notStored":false,
        "nux":"3",
        "profileMode":"PUBLIC",
        "profileStatus":"ACTIVE",
        "profileUrl":"http://profile.yahoo.com/CGGT5LNT7NXGFK64QW7FQN5UQM",
        "updated":"2014-08-29T12:00:44Z",
        "isConnected":false,
        "profileHidden":false,
        "bdRestricted":true,
        "profilePermission":"PUBLIC",
        "uri":"https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/CGGT5LNT7NXGFK64QW7FQN5UQM/profile",
        "cache":true
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I had to give permission to yahoo app to return the response

Comment: I gave the permission to my app, still was not able to get the email address.

Comment: @Logan have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I Found Solution!

You need to change your application's permission in the yahoo.
[image]

Url, which provide user info: https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/profile

And don't forget to add header Authorization: Bearer [your_access_token]